# Parse <div is="null"> using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the sub-`div` tags - all `div` tags under `<div is="null">` using Beautifulsoup. When I do this :

I am trying to scrape this page on Flipkart:

```
wiki = "https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mobiles"
url = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
div = soup.find_all('div')
```

Comment: Well most probably because they are dynamically added but without seeing how you are getting the html, it is impossible to know for sure.

Comment: Can you show an example HTML?

Comment: When adding custom attributes to HTML tags, use `data-` before the attribute name to avoid problems in the future. Your tags would be `<div class="xyz" data-is="null">`.